# Formal proof of uniform convergence with mean value theorem and on the construction of a particular open set

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, proof-writing

There are some technical details that are not clear to me within the theorem concerning the properties of mollifiers. I think they are just technical details dictated by the definition of the mollifier, but I'm not sure of the justifications I gave myself.

> Here are some definitions that was taken of PDE Evans book:

**Note** $B(0,\varepsilon)$ denote the closed ball.

[image]
where $$U_\varepsilon=\left\{x\in U\;\; \text{dist}(x,\partial U)>\varepsilon \right\}$$

> Here is a proof of a property of mollifiers:

[image]

**First Part**

> $(1)$ Who is $V$ in the first part?

Now, I must prove that $$\frac{1}{h}\left [ \eta\left(\frac{x+he_i-y}{\varepsilon}\right)-\eta\left(\frac{x-y}{\varepsilon}\right) \right]\to \frac{1}{\varepsilon}\frac{\partial\eta}{\partial x_i}\left( \frac{x-y}{\varepsilon}\right)$$ uniformly on $V$.

**My solution**

For the mean value theorem we have that $$\frac{1}{h}\left [ \eta\left(\frac{x+he_i-y}{\varepsilon}\right)-\eta\left(\frac{x-y}{\varepsilon}\right) \right]=\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\frac{\partial \eta}{\partial x_i}\left(\frac{x+\delta he_i-y}{\varepsilon} \right),$$ where $\delta\in (0,1)$.

I know that I must use the fact that $\eta_{x_i}$ are uniformly continuous as $V$ is compact.

> From here how do i get to the thesis? Could you give me a hand?

**Second Part**

For prove $(3)$ he says:

[image]

> $(2)$The open $W$ I understand how to build it. But how do we build $V$?
>
> $(3)$In this part are we assuming that $f^\varepsilon$ is defined in $V$?

My answer is the following: Since the support of each $f^\varepsilon$ is the closed ball $B(0,\varepsilon)$, can we image $f^\varepsilon$ defined in a open set $V\subseteq U$ such that $\overline{V}$ is compact and in $U$.

**Part Three**

> Why do we build $W$?

My answer is the following: if $x$ is too close to the boundary of $V$, then the ball $B_\varepsilon(x)$ could contain points that are not in $V$ and therefore we could not apply the definition of uniform continuity on $V$.

Answer (score 1):

For the first part, as h vanishes, $ \frac{x + \delta h e_i - y}{\epsilon} \rightarrow \frac{x - y}{\epsilon}$. This is where you use uniform continuity and deduce further $\eta_{x_i} ( \frac{x + \delta h e_i - y}{\epsilon}) \rightarrow \eta_{x_i}(\frac{x - y}{\epsilon})$ uniformly.

For the second part, note that we are given V and we need to find W. Since V is compact and U is open, they must be separated by some positive distance s (i.e. $ s := \text{sup}_{x \in V}\ \text{dist}(x,\partial U) > 0 $). Expand V by half of s and take the closure will give you W.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I made some changes, can you help me?

Comment: Your comment on part three is correct. To answer your question (3) under part 2, recall that f^\epsilon is defined pointwise on V (if I recall correctly). It is just the integral domain extends beyond V.